# Application crashing showing the following crash which occured on sqlite prepare statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am downloading data in the background and the size of the data is very large so its taking around 25-40 minutes to download all the data. But I am facing very strange problem that my application crashes and the crash is very occasional and it cannot be detected, what may cause this crash. But my crash point shows that the crash is on the sqlite prepare statement

```
bundleID":"com.apple.springboard","app_name":"SpringBoard","share_with_app_devs":false,"name":"SpringBoard","app_version":"1.0","is_first_party":false,"os_version":"iPhone OS 8.1.2 (12B440)","bug_type":"109","slice_uuid":"7f2c2438-50f7-34b9-a72e-d66cb0571320","build_version":"50","adam_id":0}
Incident Identifier: 510F9DCC-68F6-4C9C-93EF-DFAA2029B962
CrashReporter Key: 2e64aad38f60979f509bad033c786943b0c3b401
Hardware Model: iPad3,4
Process: SpringBoard [43]
Path: /System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard
Identifier: com.apple.springboard
Version: 50 (1.0)
Code Type: ARM (Native)
Parent Process: launchd [1]

Date/Time: 2015-02-09 14:46:07.601 +0530
Launch Time: 2015-02-09 13:08:39.774 +0530
OS Version: iOS 8.1.2 (12B440)
Report Version: 105

Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread: 0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x2368e49a 0x31146c86 0x2368e370 0x2435fd7a 0x3019fc 0x3002d8 0x10e35a 0x11188e 0x28191078 0x10db96 0x316a67b6 0x316a67a2 0x316a9f9e 0x236543ac 0x23652aac 0x235a03bc 0x235a01ce 0x2a9750a4 0x26baff9c 0xe3e4e 0x316c6aaa)

Thread 0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3178cdfc 0x31778000 + 85500
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3180ad32 0x31807000 + 15666
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3172c904 0x316e2000 + 305412
3 libc++abi.dylib 0x30a679c4 0x30a67000 + 2500
4 libc++abi.dylib 0x30a8166c 0x30a67000 + 108140
5 libobjc.A.dylib 0x31146f22 0x31140000 + 28450
6 libc++abi.dylib 0x30a7ede0 0x30a67000 + 97760
7 libc++abi.dylib 0x30a7e5a4 0x30a67000 + 95652
8 libobjc.A.dylib 0x31146d5a 0x31140000 + 27994
9 CoreFoundation 0x2368e370 0x23588000 + 1074032
10 Foundation 0x2435fd7a 0x242ce000 + 597370
11 SpringBoard 0x003019fc 0xd9000 + 2263548
12 SpringBoard 0x003002d8 0xd9000 + 2257624
13 SpringBoard 0x0010e35a 0xd9000 + 217946
14 SpringBoard 0x0011188e 0xd9000 + 231566
15 BaseBoard 0x28191078 0x28185000 + 49272
16 SpringBoard 0x0010db96 0xd9000 + 215958
17 libdispatch.dylib 0x316a67b8 0x316a5000 + 6072
18 libdispatch.dylib 0x316a67a4 0x316a5000 + 6052
19 libdispatch.dylib 0x316a9f9e 0x316a5000 + 20382
20 CoreFoundation 0x236543ac 0x23588000 + 836524
21 CoreFoundation 0x23652aac 0x23588000 + 830124
22 CoreFoundation 0x235a03bc 0x23588000 + 99260
23 CoreFoundation 0x235a01ce 0x23588000 + 98766
24 GraphicsServices 0x2a9750a4 0x2a96c000 + 37028
25 UIKit 0x26baff9c 0x26b42000 + 450460
26 SpringBoard 0x000e3e4e 0xd9000 + 44622
27 libdyld.dylib 0x316c6aac 0x316c5000 + 6828

Thread 1 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x317792a0 0x31778000 + 4768
1 libdispatch.dylib 0x316b29fc 0x316a5000 + 55804
2 libdispatch.dylib 0x316a820e 0x316a5000 + 12814

Thread 2:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x317794f0 0x31778000 + 5360
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x317792e4 0x31778000 + 4836
2 CoreFoundation 0x23654316 0x23588000 + 836374
3 CoreFoundation 0x236528bc 0x23588000 + 829628
4 CoreFoundation 0x235a03bc 0x23588000 + 99260
5 CoreFoundation 0x235a01ce 0x23588000 + 98766
6 Foundation 0x242d9bf8 0x242ce000 + 48120
7 Foundation 0x243280b8 0x242ce000 + 368824
8 UIKit 0x2701debe 0x26b42000 + 5095102
9 Foundation 0x2439eb56 0x242ce000 + 854870
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31809e90 0x31807000 + 11920
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31809e02 0x31807000 + 11778
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31807b8c 0x31807000 + 2956

Thread 3 name: com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 3:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x31779540 0x31778000 + 5440
1 libdispatch.dylib 0x316b0eee 0x316a5000 + 48878
2 MediaToolbox 0x2505cff6 0x25058000 + 20470
3 CoreMedia 0x23df7d10 0x23dc9000 + 191760
4 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31809e90 0x31807000 + 11920
5 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31809e02 0x31807000 + 11778
6 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31807b8c 0x31807000 + 2956

Thread 4:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x317794f0 0x31778000 + 5360
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x317792e4 0x31778000 + 4836
2 CoreFoundation 0x23654316 0x23588000 + 836374
3 CoreFoundation 0x236528bc 0x23588000 + 829628
4 CoreFoundation 0x235a03bc 0x23588000 + 99260
5 CoreFoundation 0x235a01ce 0x23588000 + 98766
6 SpringBoard 0x0014aab4 0xd9000 + 465588
7 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31809e90 0x31807000 + 11920
8 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31809e02 0x31807000 + 11778
9 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31807b8c 0x31807000 + 2956

Thread 5 name: com.apple.springboard.icongeneration
Thread 5:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x317794f0 0x31778000 + 5360
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x317792e4 0x31778000 + 4836
2 CoreFoundation 0x23654316 0x23588000 + 836374
3 CoreFoundation 0x236528bc 0x23588000 + 829628
4 CoreFoundation 0x235a03bc 0x23588000 + 99260
5 CoreFoundation 0x235a01ce 0x23588000 + 98766
6 SpringBoard 0x0014abd4 0xd9000 + 465876
7 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31809e90 0x31807000 + 11920
8 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31809e02 0x31807000 + 11778
9 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31807b8c 0x31807000 + 2956

Thread 6:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x317794f0 0x31778000 + 5360
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x317792e4 0x31778000 + 4836
2 IOKit 0x245d4e32 0x245b0000 + 151090
3 IOKit 0x245cdd8a 0x245b0000 + 122250
4 CoreMotion 0x23e9efd6 0x23e64000 + 241622
5 CoreMotion 0x23e9e756 0x23e64000 + 239446
6 CoreMotion 0x23e9e680 0x23e64000 + 239232
7 CoreMotion 0x23ea28da 0x23e64000 + 256218
8 CoreMotion 0x23ea021e 0x23e64000 + 246302
9 CoreMotion 0x23ea065c 0x23e64000 + 247388
10 CoreMotion 0x23ea16b8 0x23e64000 + 251576
11 CoreMotion 0x23ea4148 0x23e64000 + 262472
12 CoreMotion 0x23ea1626 0x23e64000 + 251430
13 CoreMotion 0x23edaca8 0x23e64000 + 486568
14 CoreMotion 0x23eda3e8 0x23e64000 + 484328
15 CoreMotion 0x23ed95aa 0x23e64000 + 480682
16 CoreMotion 0x23ea16e6 0x23e64000 + 251622
17 CoreMotion 0x23ea4148 0x23e64000 + 262472
18 CoreMotion 0x23ea1626 0x23e64000 + 251430
19 CoreMotion 0x23ea4148 0x23e64000 + 262472
20 CoreMotion 0x23ed87c8 0x23e64000 + 477128
21 CoreMotion 0x23e901a2 0x23e64000 + 180642
22 CoreMotion 0x23e90432 0x23e64000 + 181298
23 CoreMotion 0x23ea4192 0x23e64000 + 262546
24 CoreFoundation 0x23654d7a 0x23588000 + 839034
25 CoreFoundation 0x2365403c 0x23588000 + 835644
26 CoreFoundation 0x23652b76 0x23588000 + 830326
27 CoreFoundation 0x235a03bc 0x23588000 + 99260
28 CoreFoundation 0x235e90e6 0x23588000 + 397542
29 CoreMotion 0x23ea3e9a 0x23e64000 + 261786
30 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31809e90 0x31807000 + 11920
31 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31809e02 0x31807000 + 11778
32 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31807b8c 0x31807000 + 2956

Thread 7 name: CommonUtilities-WiFi-Thread
Thread 7:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x317794f0 0x31778000 + 5360
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x317792e4 0x31778000 + 4836
2 CoreFoundation 0x23654316 0x23588000 + 836374
3 CoreFoundation 0x236528bc 0x23588000 + 829628
4 CoreFoundation 0x235a03bc 0x23588000 + 99260
5 CoreFoundation 0x235e90e6 0x23588000 + 397542
6 CommonUtilities 0x28b3f960 0x28b3a000 + 22880
7 Foundation 0x2439eb56 0x242ce000 + 854870
8 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31809e90 0x31807000 + 11920
9 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31809e02 0x31807000 + 11778
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31807b8c 0x31807000 + 2956

Thread 8 name: NetworkLoad
Thread 8:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x317794f0 0x31778000 + 5360
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x317792e4 0x31778000 + 4836
2 CoreFoundation 0x23654316 0x23588000 + 836374
3 CoreFoundation 0x236528bc 0x23588000 + 829628
4 CoreFoundation 0x235a03bc 0x23588000 + 99260
5 CoreFoundation 0x235a01ce 0x23588000 + 98766
6 GeoServices 0x2a8a13c8 0x2a6fd000 + 1721288
7 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31809e90 0x31807000 + 11920
8 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31809e02 0x31807000 + 11778
9 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31807b8c 0x31807000 + 2956

Thread 9 name: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 9:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x317794f0 0x31778000 + 5360
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x317792e4 0x31778000 + 4836
2 CoreFoundation 0x23654316 0x23588000 + 836374
3 CoreFoundation 0x236528bc 0x23588000 + 829628
4 CoreFoundation 0x235a03bc 0x23588000 + 99260
5 CoreFoundation 0x235a01ce 0x23588000 + 98766
6 CFNetwork 0x23155952 0x230d9000 + 510290
7 Foundation 0x2439eb56 0x242ce000 + 854870
8 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31809e90 0x31807000 + 11920
9 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31809e02 0x31807000 + 11778
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31807b8c 0x31807000 + 2956

Thread 10 name: com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 10:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3178d08c 0x31778000 + 86156
1 CoreFoundation 0x23658ae2 0x23588000 + 854754
2 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31809e90 0x31807000 + 11920
3 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31809e02 0x31807000 + 11778
4 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31807b8c 0x31807000 + 2956

Thread 11 name: WiFiManager callback thread
Thread 11:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x317794f0 0x31778000 + 5360
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x317792e4 0x31778000 + 4836
2 CoreFoundation 0x23654316 0x23588000 + 836374
3 CoreFoundation 0x236528bc 0x23588000 + 829628
4 CoreFoundation 0x235a03bc 0x23588000 + 99260
5 CoreFoundation 0x235a01ce 0x23588000 + 98766
6 Foundation 0x242d9bf8 0x242ce000 + 48120
7 Foundation 0x243280b8 0x242ce000 + 368824
8 Foundation 0x2439eb56 0x242ce000 + 854870
9 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31809e90 0x31807000 + 11920
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31809e02 0x31807000 + 11778
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31807b8c 0x31807000 + 2956

Thread 12 name: Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x1777ccd0 :: NSOperation 0x176fafe0
Thread 12:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x31779540 0x31778000 + 5440
1 libdispatch.dylib 0x316b0eee 0x316a5000 + 48878
2 CoreMotion 0x23ea4138 0x23e64000 + 262456
3 CoreMotion 0x23e90186 0x23e64000 + 180614
4 UIKit 0x26f2c412 0x26b42000 + 4105234
5 Foundation 0x243892ae 0x242ce000 + 766638
6 Foundation 0x242f4348 0x242ce000 + 156488
7 Foundation 0x242e6b02 0x242ce000 + 101122
8 Foundation 0x2438bc16 0x242ce000 + 777238
9 libdispatch.dylib 0x316ae5ac 0x316a5000 + 38316
10 libdispatch.dylib 0x316a8f80 0x316a5000 + 16256
11 libdispatch.dylib 0x316afb98 0x316a5000 + 43928
12 libdispatch.dylib 0x316b0cd2 0x316a5000 + 48338
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31807e2e 0x31807000 + 3630
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31807b80 0x31807000 + 2944

Thread 13:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3178d9cc 0x31778000 + 88524
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31807ea8 0x31807000 + 3752
2 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31807b80 0x31807000 + 2944

Thread 14:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3178d9cc 0x31778000 + 88524
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31807ea8 0x31807000 + 3752
2 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31807b80 0x31807000 + 2944

Thread 15:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3178d9cc 0x31778000 + 88524
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31807ea8 0x31807000 + 3752
2 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31807b80 0x31807000 + 2944

Thread 16:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3178d9cc 0x31778000 + 88524
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31807ea8 0x31807000 + 3752
2 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31807b80 0x31807000 + 2944

Thread 17:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3178d9cc 0x31778000 + 88524
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31807ea8 0x31807000 + 3752
2 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x31807b80 0x31807000 + 2944

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
r0: 0x00000000 r1: 0x00000000 r2: 0x00000000 r3: 0x00000003
r4: 0x00000006 r5: 0x33e839dc r6: 0x33e6f840 r7: 0x00707e48
r8: 0x18bb1830 r9: 0x00000000 r10: 0x004587bb r11: 0x18bb1854
ip: 0x00000148 sp: 0x00707e3c lr: 0x3180ad37 pc: 0x3178cdfc
cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
0xd9000 - 0x4dcfff SpringBoard armv7s <7f2c243850f734b9a72ed66cb0571320> /System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard
0x2291000 - 0x229cfff Sharing armv7s /System/Library/SpringBoardPlugins/Sharing.servicebundle/Sharing
0x22a9000 - 0x22b8fff WiFiPicker armv7s /System/Library/SpringBoardPlugins/WiFiPicker.servicebundle/WiFiPicker
```

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash report!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports

Comment: He's not going to be able to symbolicate a crash report for Springboard, guys...

Comment: @IanMacDonald sorry????i dint get you???

Comment: @IanMacDonald: good catch! So it looks like the crash report is the wrong one, since it also doesn't match the text description in the question.